# Different ways to create Tasks in Swift concurrency

Tags: swift, concurrency

When running async code in a non-concurrency context, are these the same things?

`Task { ... }`

and

`Task.init{ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The `.init` is redundant, however. This is the common syntax for all initializers. `Array(...)` is the same as `Array.init(...)`.

`Task.init` takes a closure, and when there's a single closure parameter, you can drop the parentheses. (This is a form of "trailing closure syntax.") This isn't special for Task.

The full initializer is:

```
@discardableResult init(priority: TaskPriority? = nil, operation: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Success)
```

`priority` is optional, so you can drop it. And `operation` is a closure.